# ignore a parent event in PyQt or Qt in a QAction

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

Im subclassing a QAction, i want to customize some functions of the class on my own, im trying to handle the mouse events like enterEvent, mouseMoveEvent, mousePressEvent .. but i cant do it, i think i have to ignore the parent events, in order to make it work, but how could I archive this ?

```
# -------------------------------------------------------------

class ColtAction(qg.QAction):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ColtAction,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        print('action')


    def enterEvent(self, event):
        super(ColtAction,self).enterEvent(event)
        event.accept()
        print('enter')

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        super(ColtAction,self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
        print("On Hover") # event.pos().x(), event.pos().y()
        event.accept()


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        if event.button() == qc.Qt.LeftButton:
            event.accept()
            self.clicked.emit()
```

The Action is connected to a menu in another piece of the UI

```
    ###########################################
    #Menu Bar and action gestion ..
    #
    menuBar = qg.QMenuBar()        
    fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('File')       
    closeAction = ColtAction.ColtAction('CloseWindow', menuBar)        

    fileMenu.addAction(referenceAction)
    fileMenu.addAction(closeAction)
```

I cant get the events .. how could i archive this ? maybe the QMenu is controlling the Actions Events..

Comment: Just to clarify, you have a QAction nested inside another QAction? And you want the nested QAction to receive the events?

Comment: @StuartBuckingham i do not have a nested QAction, and if i have it , can you show me? im adding an Action to a Menu, im subclasins the Action because i want to change the color when i hover on then and etc, or i should do it diferently ? like sublclassins the Menu and adding the actions ?

Comment: Is it a context menu? The colour would be set in the context menu object not the action

Comment: @StuartBuckingham  , well i added the menu to a QmenuBar as menu.addMenu() , but i didnt choose a context one, should i do it in other way ?

Comment: @NestorColmenares. A [`QAction`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html) is not a `QWidget` (i.e. it does not receive events), so I'm afraid your current code cannot possibly work.

Comment: @ekhumoro  aaahh okok, thats logical, so now instead of doing this, i will subclass the QMenu Class and add the functions to it, no ?

Comment: @NestorColmenares. Yes. You can use methods like [actionAt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#actionAt) to get an action at a position in the menu. And note that there is already a [hovered signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#hovered).

Comment: @ekhumoro , you were right, i was doing it wrong, i create a single **QMenu** and add it to the **QMenuBar** and now is working more as expected